# What's the answer to part (c)?

Tags: probability, statistics

[image]

I only have trouble with part (c). For part (a), the answer is 0.0107 and for (b), the answer is 0.264. I can't figure out what to do in part (c) even though I know it's about conditional probability but I'm clueless about the setup. My guess is .0107/(.0107+0.264) = 0.0390 (3 s.f.) but I need confirmation. Thanks in advance

Comment: I recommend adjusting the title of the question to better reflect the question you are asking in order to attract more attention

Answer (score 0):

Using Bayes' Theorem,
$$\frac{(0.38)(0.0107)}{(0.38)(0.0107)+(0.62)(0.396)}$$
Essentially, the denominator is the total probability of a randomly selected person having a reaction time greater than 0.65 and the numerator is the portion of that probability coming from group $X$.